# Get/Set non-static String to static string to pass through Java

Tags: java, string, static, non-static

First thing first; I understand that it is not possible to call a non-static method from a static method as detailed here.

**Q:** I was wondering if I can set the string (non-static) as static with a constructor method so that I can pass the string staticly across java classes and to JNI:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   String argument = "iqsrc://"+ arguments.getText().toString();
   Uri myUri = Uri.parse(argument);
   myIntent.setData(myUri);
   startActivity(myIntent);

String arguments = new argument
//Used to pass static string to /from java
```

and will every time the non-static string changes a new static value be changing as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First thing first; I understand that it is not possible to call a static method from a non-static method

First things first, you **can** call a static method from a non-static method. You can't call a non-static method from a static method.

You can set a static variable from a non-static method if that is your intention:

```
static String foo;

void myNonStaticMethod() {
    foo = "bar";
}
```

Comment: Thank you...sorry for the dyslexia.

Comment: Ähemm ... it is news for me that one alledgedly cannot call non-static methods from static ones? After all, main *is* a static method, and from there it all begins. If it were as you said, no non-static method could ever be get called.

Comment: @Ingo I think we're talking semantics here. You can not call a non-static method *without calling on an instance*., eg `new MyClass().myNonStaticMethod();`, but not just `myNonStaticMethod();` on its own.

Comment: @Bohemian Calling a non-static method is, of course, by definition always using a receiver, even if you don't need to write it explicitly when the receiver is supposed to be `this`. Hence, we can say there is basically only one way to call non-static methods. Anyway, stating that one cannot call non-static methods from static ones is simply wrong. It is just that you can't use `this`, because there is none.